# Where did Chloe and Charlie go in Uncharted 3?

Tags: uncharted-3

Around the start of the 3rd act of *Uncharted 3: Drake's Deception*

> Chloe and Charlie seem to just not be there anymore.

What happened to them? Where did they go?

Comment: Doesn't chapter 3 have the young Drake still?

Comment: the 3rd act, not 3rd chapter.

Comment: Okay. I don't recall it mentioning acts ever. Just chapters.

Comment: I just meant in the last 3rd of the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chloe and Charlie are gone after Chapter 9 in Syira, about halfway through the game. You can watch the final cutscene in the video below.

Chloe tries to talk Nate out of continuining on and Cutter urges him to continue, but no specific reference is made after that as to what happens to them.

They just don't show up anymore. Cutter did break his leg, so it's understandable he doesn't continue on. Chloe obviously doesn't believe it's worth it to continue on, that's about all you can assume I think.

Comment: Wiki article? Not sure what you're talking about!

Comment: I removed the reference anyhow. Your answer read very much like the wiki articles I saw because it mentions Chloe helping Cutter with medical attention which can only be assumed, apologies if you didn't grab it from there.

Comment: No my answer was just from my experience, I said presumably because that's my best guess as to what happened.

Comment: Understood. I think a better overall answer would be, the writers ran out of ideas and here's where the story started falling apart. Disappointed in this game.

Comment: I felt like Chloe and Cutter were involved in some kind of romantic relationship, and although it wasn't explicitly said, that would play a part in Chloe's not continuing with Drake and Sully.

Answer (score 3):

Answer below:

> Charlie broke his leg at the Citadel when he jumped from the roof to avoid the fire. That would count him out of just about everything Drake does in the game!
>  
>  When driving away from the Citadel in the bus, Chloe indicated that she didn't think their quest was worth the risks they were taking, so she left and presumably helped Charlie to get medical attention and to return back home.